# Django and zinnia: NoReverseMatch for all views after upgrading

Tags: django, zinnia

I had `zinnia` (0.14.1) working fine with my `django` (1.6.6) app.  I then upgraded my django to 1.8.0 and my zinnia to 0.15.1 and made several of the required changes, including changing the name of the template tags from `zinnia_tags` to `zinnia` in my custom templates.

I ran into a problem with `'zinnia' is not a registered namespace` but resolved that by making the following change in my project's main `urls.py`:

```
# url(r'^blog/', include('zinnia.urls')),
url(r'^blog/', include('zinnia.urls', namespace='zinnia')),
```

But now I'm getting `NoReverseMatch` errors for all my pages.  For example:

> NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'zinnia_entry_archive_day' with arguments
>   '(u'2015', u'02', u'23')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0
>   pattern(s) tried: []

and

> NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'zinnia_tag_detail' with arguments
>   '(u'Alumni',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s)
>   tried: []

I can't figure out what's going on.  Could it be another setting I have to update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that because I had adapted and customized the zinnia templates, and the namespace had changed, I also had to change the syntax wherever a `url` call was made.  The underscores become colons.

Convert

```
<a href="{% url 'zinnia_tag_detail' tag %}" rel="tag">
```

and

```
<a href="{% url 'zinnia_entry_archive_year' date|date:"Y" %}" rel="archives">{{ date|date:"Y" }}</a>
```

to

```
<a href="{% url 'zinnia:tag_detail' tag %}" rel="tag">
```

and

```
<a href="{% url 'zinnia:entry_archive_year' date|date:"Y" %}" rel="archives">{{ date|date:"Y" }}</a>
```